# Before the Babylonian Exile of The Kingdom of Yehudah, was there any type of formal schooling in Ancient Israel (Northern and Southern Kingdom)?

Tags: history, yeshiva-school, chinuch-education

Doing research on how educational practices in [Ancient Yisrael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_education) (both the Northern and Southern Kingdom), I could only find reference to how schooling (formalized) was done post-[Babylonian Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_education_in_ancient_Israel_and_Judah#House_of_the_teacher).  I did find some insight explaining that the brunt of education was done by the [tribes, communities, and households](https://amitchildren.org/ancient-jewish-education/) (makes sense due to everybody not being qualified to do everything):

> "prior to the exile of 586/587 B.C.E, the primary teachers were the
> shevet (tribe) and the family, particularly parents, and education was
> focused on the children. The Jews being originally nomadic tribes, the
> training involved participation in the various agrarian occupations,
> such as farming, tent-making, making of tools, and fishing. Knowledge
> was passed from generation to generation through stories and
> allegories"

Did formal, centralized schooling come to existence only after the Israelites returned from Babylon? If there was formalized schooling prior, how were the classrooms ran? What was the pedagogy?  How were teachers trained? How long was the average student in school for? Did wealth play a role? Were women educated? As always book references, articles, research, and personal insight are welcomed. Todah Rabbah/thank you.

Comment: Is the Gemara in Bava Basra 21 about Yehoshua ben Gamla too late for the desired period?

Comment: History of Abecedaries : https://www.thetorah.com/article/pe-before-ayin-in-biblical-pre-exilic-acrostics

Comment: Where does it say though that it was used in a teaching / pedagogic environment?

Comment: @חִידָה Shalom shalom, may you explain and unpack that reference bevakasha?

Comment: @Dov Shalom Shalom, Todah Rabbah for beautiful reference. What time period/era is that? Correct me if I'm wrong but is that during the Roman Occupation?

Comment: @יהודה - if it was recorded in Talmud Bavli I would imagine it was around then which is why I asked if this was too late a period of time for what you're asking?

Comment: See also Sanhedrin 94b https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.94b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @Dov I understand, Todah Rabbah.  I do prefer an earlier time period.

Comment: @Loewian Shalom and todah for that.  Chizkiyahu HaMelech knew how to get the job done lol